# in DDD, how update entites of a bounded context when happens something in entities of another bounded context?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have two bounded context. Components, that it is used to handle stocksm and I have another bounded context, Purchases, to handle the purchases to providers.

For stock handle, I would like to know what quantity is pending to receive, so I was thinking to have a property in  component that it would be PendindQuantity.

In this solution, when I accepted a purchase, I would have to update too the property of the component, increasing the quantity.

But I am think it is not a good solution, because a bounded context is modifying entitues from another bounded context. I think that, because if I am not wrong, bounded context should to be isolated contexts and a bounded context shouldn't to modify entities from another context.

Also this make me think in which layer should I do that. In the domain I guess it is not the place, beacuse each domain belgons to each bounded context, so it should to be in an upper layer.

So the next step is the application layer. It could use the domains of the both bounded contexts, accept the purchase, and if it is correct, update the quantity in the component. But I want this to be a unit of work process, in some way I have to have a repository to modify component and purchases. This it would be extra repository, because at first I have one repository to handle componts in an isolated way and another repository for purchases.

Another option that I think it would be possible it is not not have a field in the component to have the pending quatity. I have the relation of the component in purchase, because the purchase have a line for the component that is requested, so I could know the pending quantity of the component counting the quatinty of the component of all the purchases which state is accepted. When a purchase is delivered, it will pass to the next state, received. So I know that the pending quantity it is all the quantity of the accepted purchases.

This solution requieres more resources in the way to know this data I need a more complex query, it is normally I prefer to have a field with this kind of data. But it is more complex to program.

In summary, is bad practice the first option, to have a field for the pending quantity becuse the architecture of the application is more complex? Should I go for a solution like the second one? Or are there another solution for this kind of problems, when I need to update an entity of an entity of a bounded conext because something happens in the entity of another bounded context?

Thanks.